# Why does QTreeView not fire a Drop or Move event during drag and drop?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtreeview

I was attempting to figure out an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989923/what-signal-do-i-utilize-to-check-an-element-after-a-drag-drop-event) question when I realized the events I'm looking for aren't occurring.

```
import sys, new
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore 

class MainForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainForm, self).__init__(parent)

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()

        for k in range(0, 4):
            rootItem = self.model.invisibleRootItem()
            parentItem = QtGui.QStandardItem(QtCore.QString("Parent: %0").arg(k))
            for i in range(0, 5):
                item = QtGui.QStandardItem(QtCore.QString("Value: %0").arg(i))
                parentItem.appendRow(item)
            rootItem.appendRow(parentItem)

        self.view = QtGui.QTreeView()
        self.view.setModel(self.model)
        self.view.setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.view.expandAll()
        self.view.installEventFilter(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.view)


    def eventFilter(self, object, event):
        if object is self.view:
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Move:
                print "Moved!"
                event.accept()
                return True
            else:
                event.ignore()
                return super(MainForm, self).eventFilter(object, event)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MainForm()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

My idea to solve that problem was to utilize an event filter and watch for the `QtCore.QEvent.Move` event. This is because the DragDrop mode is set to `QtGui.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove`

> The view accepts move (not copy) operations only from itself. - [Documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qabstractitemview.html#DragDropMode-enum)

The problem is, this event is never fired. Neither is `QtCore.QEvent.Drop`. Instead I see the following [events](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html):

- `QtCore.QEvent.ChildAdded`
- `QtCore.QEvent.ChildRemoved`
- `QtCore.QEvent.Timer`
- `QtCore.QEvent.ToolTip`

The drag and drop IS successful. I can move node around as expected. What is happening to the `Move` or `Drop` events though?

If I remove the check `if object is self.view` and just watch for these two events in general, I still don't see them occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to track events on the viewport, and filter `DragMove` and `Drop`:

```
    self.view.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

def eventFilter(self, object, event):
    if object is self.view.viewport():
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.DragMove:
            print "Moved!"
        elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Drop:
            print "Dropped!"
    return super(MainForm, self).eventFilter(object, event)
```